How to filter a Pandas DataFrame without returning a slice?
Here is a statement which filters a Pandas DataFrame:
selected_options = ['option_1', 'option_2']

df = df[df['my_col'].isin(selected_options)]

This returns a slice object. That causes warnings to be raised when performing mutating operations on the slice.
How can I filter a dataframe without having a slice be returned?
One possible way I know of is to call .copy().
df = df[df['my_col'].isin(selected_options)].copy()

Is there a more direct approach using some function which performs filtering operations rather than slicing operations?

what version of pandas are you on? pandas 2 ideally shouldnt raise such errors

@sammywemmy 2.2 I believe

You can use .query
Data:
import pandas as pd

selected_options = ["option_1", "option_2"]
data = {"spam": [1, 2, 3, 4], "ham": ["option_1", "option_2", "option_3", "option_4"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

Code:
df = df.query(expr="ham in @selected_options")
print(df)

Output:
   spam       ham
0     1  option_1
1     2  option_2

